# Java Method to Writer a new line to file each time called

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to create a java method that will write to a CSV file that has already been created. Each time the method is called from the class, it should append all the fields from that class, separated by commas, and then skip to the next line.

My class overall looks something like:

```
Student bob = new Student("Bob", "Johnson", "10111990", "B+");
// call bob on the addStudentInfo:
bob.addStudentInfo(); 
//this should add to the file student.txt with a line containing the 4 fields.
```

EDIT: woops, didn't frame a question, though ya'll really felt like answering it in the most condescending way as possible, thanks for that.

I want to know what line should be written that does that. Like, I don't want to copy paste my whole code since I can't share it all. Basically, I have the parts of it that can actually write to the file, create the file, etc. . . I just need some line in the code that skips a line in that file to the next.

Comment: And is your question "Write the code for me" or something else?

Comment: Very well and your question?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following appends a student record to the file. Irrespective of the old contents.

```
public class Student {

    private static final char SEPARATOR = ',';
    private static final String NEWLINE = "\r\n";
    private static final Charset CHARSET = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    public void addStudentInfo() throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(".../student.txt");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (!Files.exists(path)) {
            sb.append("\uFEFF")
                .append("First name").append(SEPARATOR)
                ...
                .append(NEWLINE);
        }
        sb.append(...).append(SEPARATOR).append(...).append(NEWLINE);
        Files.write(path,
            Collections.singletonList(sb),
            CHARSET,
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }
```

This uses a Windows line-ending and a UTF-8 encoding. So on every computer this application will render the same file format, whether Linux, China or whatsoever.

When the file is empty a header line is written.
In that case as the first character a Unicode BOM character (a zero-width space) is written U+FEFF.
This marks the file as Unicode, as otherwise Windows would assume the current Windows ANSI encoding, which varies regionally. *(However the BOM is optional, ugly, invisible and can play havoc, when reading all in.)*

StringBuilder is a CharSequence (as is String), and this version of Files.write writes an `Iterable<CharSequence>`; hence we create a List containing one element.